# Is it possible to bind RelativeLayout constraints?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am using the following XAML code to render some data in a ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding myData}"
          RowHeight="230">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <ViewCell.View>
            <RelativeLayout Padding="1">
              <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayoutTitle"
                           Padding="5" 
                           Orientation="Vertical" 
                           VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                           RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
                           RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.6}">
                <Label Text="{Binding myText}"
                       FontSize="Medium"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       TextColor="Black">
                </Label>
              </StackLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

The data is rendering OK. Now, what I would like to do is to use banding for the Factor property of the RelativeYConstranit to position the respective StackLayout based on some calculation. Something like this ***(see the Factor property):***

```
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor={Binding someValue}}"
```

But, when running the App I am getting an error.

Does anyone knows if it's possible to using binding expression for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem. "Factor" is not BindingProperty. Therefore now is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar thing and failed to bind factor for YConstraint, here is an explanation of why it doesn't work

From the documentation:

> In C#, relative constraints are defined as functions. Concepts like Factor aren't there, but can be implemented manually.

The error message I got:

> Cannot assig property "Factor": Property does not exist, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

Conclusion:
There is no bindable property (note it has to be a bindable property otherwise you can not bind) Factor in the underlying code so it is not possible to bind.